# How to create JSON class or construct from sample data in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a requirement to read JSON data from Source A and send it to Destination B. A and B has different JSON "schema" and i have to parse the data from A, then construct JSON object to send to B. I am trying to figure out best way to construct the JSON object for B.

JSON from A looks like :

```
{
  "timestamp": 123,
  "endTimestamp": 128,
  "state": "OK",
  "message":"send something"

}
```

I need to send the following to B:

```
{   
  "id": "123+128",
  "cat": {
    "dept":"xyz",
    "type":"abc"
  },
  "description":"send something"
  "status":"OK"
  "version": "10"
}
```

From Source A, I can create an object easily using : `request.json` method to read key value pairs to retrieve data.  (Both A & B are HTTP end points which accepts POST request).

How can i easily create a Python class/JSON construct to map values to keys required by B? Some of these values can be hard coded.

Mapping :

```
timestamp+endTimestamp --> id
message --> description 
state --> status
```

Other values required by B can be hard coded.

Note that i have simplified the JSON data to make easy to explain. In actual use case, i have more than 15 fields. In order to make maintaining code easy,

1) I am thinking of creating a sample JSON file required by B.

2) Load the sample data to construct Object from JSON.

```
with open('json_sample.json', 'r') as f:
  loaded_json = json.load(f)
  data=json.dumps(loaded_json)
```

3) Do the mapping

```
  data[description] = sourceA[message]
  data[id] = str(soureceA[timestamp])+str(sourceA[endTimestamp])
  data[status]= sourceA[state]
```

I am primarily trying to avoid creating dict or tuples for all keys required by B. Is it a good approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: `I am primarily trying to avoid creating dict or tuples for all keys required by B. Is it a good approach?` why?

Comment: `data=json.dumps(loaded_json)`, `data` here is a string. `data[description]` string is immutable, this will fail. you probably will want to use `loaded_json["description"]` and when returning use `json.dumps`

Comment: There are some key value pair not going to change very often, thought loading them file as a template would be easier for length of the program for readability.